# ¿Cómo hacer buscador PHP con multiples criterios?

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin, select

La idea es hacer funcionar un buscador y devuelva una consulta según varios parámetros.

Este código busca por rango de edades y altura,  pero sólo filtra bien los resultados por edad. Al añadir más parámetros en la consulta deja de funcionar. He probado varias formas en la consulta `$sql`, cambiando los `BETWEEN` de sitio y los paréntesis, pero nada,  creo que el fallo puede venir por ahí .. No sé, si alguien tiene una sugerencia se lo agradecería.

```
<form class="navbar-form form-inline"
  role="search" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
  <div class="input-group">

    <label style="float:left;margin-top:3%;color:#F3E2A9">Edad</label>
    <select style="margin:10px; border-radius:3px;width:12%;float:left;"
      id="edad1" name="edad1" class="form-control" id="sel1">

      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>

    </select>

    <label style="float:left;margin-top:3%;color:#F3E2A9">a</label>
    <select style="margin:10px; border-radius:3px;width:12%;float:left;"
      id="edad2" name="edad2" class="form-control" id="sel2">

      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>

    <label style="padding-left:3%;float:left;margin-top:3%;color:#F3E2A9">Altura</label>
    <select style="padding-left:3%;margin:10px; border-radius:3px;width:12%;float:left;"
      class="form-control" id="sel3" name="cm1">
      <option value="155">155</option>
      <option value="156">156</option>
    </select>

    <label style="float:left;margin-top:3%;color:#F3E2A9">a</label>
    <select style="padding-right:2%;margin:10px; border-radius:3px;width:12%;float:left;"
     class="form-control" id="sel4" name="cm2">
      <option value="155">155</option>
      <option value="180">180</option>
    </select>
```

// codigo PHP que procesa los datos del formulario

```
<?php

$edad1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['edad1']);
$edad2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['edad2']);
$cm1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['cm1']);
$cm2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['cm2']);

//  NO funciona. consulta de los parametros altura y edad.
$sql= "SELECT *
  FROM pacientes
  WHERE altura
    BETWEEN $cm1 AND $cm2 AND (
      fecha BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL $edad2 YEAR AND
      CURDATE() - INTERVAL $edad1 YEAR)  ORDER BY id DESC
    )
";

// SÍ funciona - sólo parametro edad
// $sql_prod = "SELECT * FROM pacientes WHERE fecha BETWEEN CURDATE() -
// INTERVAL $edad2 YEAR AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL $edad1 YEAR ORDER BY id DESC";

// CORRECIÓN; esta consulta funciona buscando parametro por edad y altura.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pacientes
  WHERE altura
    BETWEEN $cm1 AND $cm2 AND
    fecha BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL $edad2 YEAR AND
    CURDATE() - INTERVAL $edad1 YEAR ORDER BY id DESC
";
```

Comment: ¿Has comprobado de que tipo son los datos que recibes?, ¿son de tipo `INT`?, ¿y en la DB son también de tipo `INT`? Por otro lado, puedes hacer un echo del `SQL` que genera el `PHP` en vez de ejecutarlo, copiarlo y llevarlo a `phpmyadmin` a ver que te dice.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya lo solucioné. Hice un echo de la consulta como dijiste y lo probé en SQL. Al final era cuestion de un parentesis mal puesto. dejo la solucion corregida por si alguien le sirve. Soy nueva aqui, hay que hacer algo, hay que marcar la respuesta buena, cómo si?

Comment: Hola, en este caso como no dí una `respuesta` con solución completa como tal, si no que simplemente hago un `comentario` con una recomendación, no puedes hacer mucho más. En el caso de que fuera una respuesta completa, pues existe una opción de aceptar esta respuesta como solución, en esos casos es recomendable darle para poder ayudar a los demás usuarios.